# Laravel eloquent model - model extends model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

is it possible to extend a laravel 4 eloquent model with another model, let's say i have a user model extending the eloquent class and additionally there is a second class, a administrator class extending the user class?

If i just linked the administrator class to the user i'd have to access the administrators attributes by first getting the administrator attribute of the user and then getting the admins attributes.

EDIT:

Let's say I have the Administrator not extending the User. I'd have to access e.g. the phone number(a administrators attribute) like this

`$user = User::find(1);
$phone = $user->administrator->phone;`

but by letting the Administrator extend the User I am able to access the phone number directly  like this maybe
`$user = Administrator::find(1);` (Note that the id passed to find the Administrator is the same like the one I use to get the user. Normally I would have to pass the real id of the entry in the Administrator database)
`$phone = $user->phone;`
At the same time it would be possible to access an attribute of the user class e.g. `$phone = $user->email;`

or maybe there is a better solution to achieve this or it makes no sense to use it like this, if so, feel free to tell me

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Why are you asking a question before actually trying to do what you described and then, according to result, act upon it? I don't know much about Laravel's Eloquent, but I know you can extend a class that extended another class, which is one of the reasons why OO was invented.

Comment: because I also wanted to get an evaluation of how practical my idea is

Comment: @N.B.: The problem with models is that, while you can do anything... **not everything is a good idea**. His would have led to a lot of confusion when using relationships.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld - yes, I agree that not everything is a good idea, but trial and error cannot be tossed out of the learning process just like that.

Comment: @N.B.: this one would've lured Moritz in some pretty bad habits and he would have only noticed when he tries doing an association. In other words, pretty far down the line. Trial and error is a good thing, but sometimes, it's a good thing to voice an idea and see if it pans out okay, and kudos to him for doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good idea in principle, a bad idea in practice. If both of your models use the same table and the only difference is a field, there is **no point** in adding model pollution. Worse still, you'd have to modify the way Laravel handles relationships (one-to-many) to intelligently return either an Administrator or User object when getting users through other models.

Consider doing the following instead:

```
 class User extends \Laravel\Eloquent {
     public function isAdministrator() { return !!$this->is_admin; }
     public static function findAdministrator($r=false) {
        if ($r) return self::where("is_admin","=",true)->where("id","=",(int)$r);
        else return self::where("is_admin","=",true);
     }
 }
```

Doing this opens the two new methods on the model: `isAdministrator`, which returns boolean true if the user is an admin, boolean false otherwise. `findAdministrator`, which behaves like `find`  but selectively picks admins.

This allows you to not have two models for what is essentially a relationship (an admin remains an user, after all). It also allows you to easily pick out what you need through useful, atomic methods.

Comment: `findAdministrator`  could also be expressed as a scope!