# Laravel eloquent - model extends another model

Tags: php, database-design, laravel, model, eloquent

So I'm building an app to support a two sided marketplace, where there are buyers ("users") and sellers ("creatives") and each would have different profiles. However they both have to register and login the same way, and each would have different relationships of various kinds (one to many and many to many). I'm wondering if it makes sense to have your standard Users model and have a "Creatives" class extend the user model.

Here's a break down of my models, fields and relationships, so you can see how some things are shared yet the creatives have more stuff.

Models:

- Users (buyers)
- Creatives (the sellers, that sell a "talk")
- Portfolio Images (belong to the creatives)
- Expertise (these work like tags)
- Talk (scheduled date and time to meet with a creative)
- Problem (think support ticket, user submits a problem with some info)

The two main models:

Users

- Name
- Email
- Password
- Stripe Customer Id (gets set later)
- Avatar
- Role (assuming I need this, thinking either a 1 or 0)

Creative

Has all of the above PLUS:

- Price
- bio
- live (whether their profile is live on the site)

Also "creatives" have "images" (one to many), and "expertise" (many to many).
Users have "problems" (one to many), and schedule talks (one to many).

I'm thinking that I'll actually have two different signup forms one for regular users and one for creatives, then each has their own on boarding process one for the creatives to fill out their profile with the images and stuff and one for regular users to get them to schedule talks and/or post problems.

Doe any of this make sense? Am I thinking of this wrong? Red flags or things to keep in mind?

the only thing I came across was this: [Laravel eloquent model - model extends model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565486/laravel-eloquent-model-model-extends-model)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well I guess to specific and sprawling of a question? Well went ahead and made a migration, one addition is that I added a foreign key to the creatives (extending the user class) to reference a user id. We'll see how it goes. I find the laravel / laracasts / internet to be a little light on the more complicated model interactions info, especially when it comes to relationships. It either assumes your a total newb and only explains a model with none, or assumes your an expert and goes into polymorphic. I feel perpetually stuck in this limbo for many things re: frameworks. Sigh.

Comment: I would just keep a single User model and keep a property stating the user type. this will make it easier to integrate authentication and if a third user type comes in all i have to do is add a new type constant.